# Reading a text file using streamreader and displaying results in listbox

Tags: c#, wpf

I have some information in a text file which I want to read and display in a listbox in WPF. This is what I have in the text file:

```
First Name: ABC
Last Name: def
Mobile: 5453553535
email: abc@gmail.com
```

And this is the code:

```
private void listView1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    string text;
    FileStream aFile = new FileStream("D:\\PhoneBook.txt", FileMode.Open);
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(aFile);
    text = sr.ReadLine();
    // Read data in line by line.
    while (text != null)
    {
        foreach (string info in text.Split(',')) 
        {
            listView1.Items.Add(info);
        }       
    }
    sr.Close();
}
```

Every time I run the program the listbox is just empty and freezes. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried running your code in debug mode and stepping through to see what is actually happening? Also, I would highly suggest you look into using `using` statements rather than call sr.Close(). https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement

Comment: Throw away all that code and just write `listView1.ItemsSource = File.ReadAllLines("D:\\PhoneBook.txt");`. The `text.Split(',')` part seems pointless, as there are apparently no commas in your file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a readline in the loop:

```
private void listView1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    string text;
    FileStream aFile = new FileStream("D:\\PhoneBook.txt", FileMode.Open);
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(aFile);
    text = sr.ReadLine();
    // Read data in line by line.
    while (text != null)
    {
        foreach (string info in text.Split(',')) 
        {
            listView1.Items.Add(info);
        }        
        // read the next line here
        text = sr.ReadLine();      
    }

    sr.Close();
}
```

But a better approach would be:

```
while(!sr.EndOfStream)
{
    text = sr.ReadLine();
    // now write ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not updating "text" within the loop - You just need to add text = sr.ReadLine(); in there to avoid your while loop lasting forever!

That said, You could stand to just use File.ReadAllLines() - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalllines?view=netframework-4.7.2